# How can i create white space between 2 words in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

### Javascript Code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.write(“Hello There!”);
document.write(“I’m a Boy”);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

---

- **> here there are 2 document.write sections. How should we create white space between those 2, when the output will display. Like in one single line, Hello There! (Atleast 4 white spaces for an example) I’m a Boy**

Comment: do you mean add a new line?

Comment: @004123 nope nope... in that line only... (example: Hello There![add white space between these 2]I’m a Boy) like this.

Comment: Try my answer @MangeshParmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `&nbsp;` where you want to add space.

```
<script>
      document.write(“Hello There! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I am boy”);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&nbsp;` to add white space.

like

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
     document.write("Hello There!");
     document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
     document.write("I’m a Boy");
   </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```js
document.write("Hello There!");
document.write("\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0I’m a Boy");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a newline, use `<br />` (not `\n` because you're writing HTML):

```js
document.write("Hello There!");
document.write("<br />");
document.write("I'm a Boy!");
```

If you want a space, just write a space:

```js
document.write("Hello There!");
document.write(" ");
document.write("I'm a Boy!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic answer would be to just add a space at the end of your strings:

```
document.write("Hello There! ");
document.write("Hello There!");
```

`Hello There! Hello There!` would be the result.

If you want more than 1 space, you'd have to use unbreakable spaces:

```
document.write("Hello There!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
document.write("Hello There!");
```

If it's just a fun exercice for you, it's fine, but usually, you don't want to style with spaces. You should wrap your text in `p`s or other html elements and use css.